# Visual Studio 2013 publishing fails and reports "non-existing" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, publish

So I made myself a C#-WebApi REST Service.
When I build/run my application in Visual Studio everything works perfectly.
But everytime I try to publish my project as a filesystem, two errors appear in the error list. The strange thing here is that these errors disappear after a few seconds and no errors are shown.

ErroMessages:

- 'Yow.Contracts.IEvent' does not contain a definition for 'CreatetionDate' and no extension method 'CreationDate' accepting a first argument of type 'Yow.Contracts.IEvent' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
- 'Yow.Contracts.IEvent' does not contain a definition for 'Color' and no extension method 'Color' accepting a first argument of type 'Yow.Contracts.IEvent' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

In this Method the errors occur:

```
public override void CopyProperties(object other)
        {
            base.CopyProperties(other);
            Contracts.IEvent _event = other as Contracts.IEvent;
            if (_event != null)
            {
                this.Description = _event.Description;
                this.Enddate = _event.Enddate;
                this.Host = _event.Host;
                this.Location = _event.Location;
                this.Name = _event.Name;
                this.Color = _event.Color;
                this.CreationDate = _event.CreationDate;
            }
        }
```

Interface which my class implements looks like this:

```
namespace Yow.Contracts
{
    public interface IEvent : DataObjectBase.IDataObject
    {
        string Host { get; set; }
        string Location { get; set; }
        DateTime Startingdate { get; set; }
        DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Privacy { get; set; }
        string State { get; set; }
        string Agerestriction { get; set; }
        int Age { get; set; }
        string Color { get; set; }
        DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the publish succeed or fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such errors that disappear shortly usually mean there are some issues with project references. Try to search for the errors messages in the Output panel, it might contain something related to missing references. I also have a suspicion that you would see the same behavior if you ReBuild the solution.

Comment: The output panel didn't tell me anything besides the errors I already mentioned. When I rebuild everything works perfectly.

Comment: It seem there was a issue with the references. After I removed my my project and added it back it worked.
Thank you :)